# How to use conditional styles with MUI v5 using emotion styled

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm migrating from MUI v4 to v5. In v4 I was using `clsx` with `TextField` to add conditional styles.

```
export const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    root: {
      // ...
    },
    valid: {
      "& fieldset": {
        borderColor: theme.palette.success.main,
        borderWidth: 2
      }
    }
  })
);

const classes = useStyles();
<TextField
  {...props}
  className={clsx(classes.root, { [classes.valid]: isValid })}
/>
```

I'm trying to find a similar approach in MUI v5. Is there any alternative for conditional styles in MUI v5 other than with `clsx` and `makestyles`.

Let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 8):

There are multiple ways to do that:

#### 1. Conditional operator

Use this if you want to conditionally set a property based on a boolean value.

```
const Box1 = styled(Box, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "showBorder"
})(({ showBorder }) => ({
  border: showBorder ? "solid red 5px" : "none"
}));
```

```
<Box1 />
<Box1 showBorder />
```

#### 2. Dictionary

Use this if you want to conditionally set a property based on multiple values.

```
import { styled, darken } from "@mui/material/styles";

const colors = {
  hauntedForest: "#0b5b38",
  redLust: "#b20608",
  spaceExplorer: "#1244a1",
  default: "#000000"
};

const Box2 = styled(Box, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "variant"
})(({ variant }) => ({
  backgroundColor: colors[variant] ?? colors.default,
  border: "5px solid " + darken(colors[variant] ?? colors.default, 0.3)
}));
```

```
<Box2 variant="hauntedForest" />
<Box2 variant="redLust" />
<Box2 variant="spaceExplorer" />
<Box2 />
```

#### 3. [Short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation) + Spread operator

Use this if you want to conditionally set multiple properties.

```
const Box3 = styled(Box, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "isFancy" && prop !== "isFancyBorder"
})(({ theme, isFancy, isFancyBorder }) => ({
  ...(isFancy && {
    borderRadius: theme.shape.borderRadius,
    boxShadow: "0 4px 6px gray, 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08)",
    backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(90deg, #be5af7, #165b91)"
  }),
  ...(isFancyBorder && {
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    border: "5px solid transparent",
    borderImage: "linear-gradient(90deg, #be5af7, #165b91)",
    borderImageSlice: 1
  })
}));
```

```
<Box3 isFancy />
<Box3 isFancyBorder />
```

All of the methods above can also be applied when using [`sx` props](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69500502/9449426) since they use JS object to describe the styles.

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 2):

This seem to work for me

Using sx

```
sx={{ px: variable ? 8 : null }}
```

sx with breakpoint

```
sx={{ px: { md: variable ? 8 : null } }}
```

prop

```
 <Typography align={variable ? 'center' : 'inherit'}>
```

Using className

```
    className={ variable ||'class-name'}
```