# How to implement conditional styles in Material UI v5 sx prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Looking for clever conditional styles in Material UI v5's `sx` prop. One example I have played with is:

```
const statusStyle = (status) => {
  switch (status) {
    case "aborted":
      return "#D66460";
      break;
    case "queue":
      return "#6685F0";
      break;
    case "processing":
      return "#F0E666";
      break;
    default:
      return "#60D660";
  }
};

<TableRow
  key={job.job}
  sx={{ color: statusStyle(status) }}
>
```

But I'm wondering if someone has come up with something more elegant?

Answer (score 55):

If it's just a simple mapping with a primitive key, you can use an object:

```
const statusColors = {
  aborted: '#D66460',
  queue: '#6685F0',
  processing: '#F0E666',
}
```

```
sx={{ color: statusColors[job.status] ?? defaultColor }}
```

If you want to pass a style object conditionally, you can use the spread syntax `...`, this is how the MUI team [apply the styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e0cdcd130db60d252c4382570844ea7278649a08/packages/mui-material/src/Button/Button.js#L94-L116) to the components with different variants and states:

```
sx={{
  color: defaultColor,
  backgroundColor: defaultBgcolor,
  ...(job.status === 'aborted' && {
    color: color1,
    backgroundColor: bgcolor1,
  }),
  ...(job.status === 'queue' && {
    color: color2,
    backgroundColor: bgcolor2,
  }),
  ...(job.status === 'processing' && {
    color: color3,
    backgroundColor: bgcolor3,
  }),
}}
```

Comment: When I try something like statusColors[job.status] i get `No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{ aborted: string; queue: string; processing: string; }`

Comment: @isea I'm not sure what is happening. Can you reproduce the error in [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/boxsx-material-demo-forked-t8yrz?file=/demo.tsx) codesandbox? It works fine in there.

Comment: Hmm, yeah that is what I would expect. I think the error is coming from strict linting on the project I'm working on.

Comment: @isea you can copy your project's tsconfig in [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/boxsx-material-demo-forked-t8yrz?file=/tsconfig.json) and see what's wrong.

Comment: @isea probably it's a typescript error, can change to `statusColors[job.status as keyof statusColors]`

Comment: @NearHuscarl I have tried to apply spread operator as suggested but it is giving me `Spread types may only be created from object types.` this error

`` sx={{
          p: 0,
          ...(open && {
            '&:before': {
              zIndex: 1,
              content: "''",
              width: '100%',
              height: '100%',
              borderRadius: '50%',
              position: 'absolute',
              bgcolor: theme => alpha(theme.palette.grey[900], 0.8),
            },
          }),
        }}``

Answer (score 6):

This seem to work for me

```
const [emailStatus, setEmailStatus] = useState('');
  const [emailStatusText, setEmailStatusText] = useState('');
  const [isEmailSubmitted, setIsEmailSubmitted] = useState(false);
```

...

```
return response.json().then((data) => {
            const { success, error } = data;
            setEmailStatus(success ? 'success' : 'error');
            setEmailStatusText(success || error);
            return data;
          });
```

...

```
{isEmailSubmitted && (
              <Typography
                sx={{
                  textAlign: 'left',
                  color:
                    emailStatus === 'success'
                      ? theme.palette.success.main
                      : theme.palette.error.main,
                }}
              >
                {emailStatusText}
              </Typography>
            )}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [`SxProps`](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/master/packages/mui-system/src/styleFunctionSx/styleFunctionSx.d.ts#L70) declaration, it can accept `SystemStyleObject`, a function, or a `ReadonlyArray` of `boolean|Function|SystemStyleObject`:

> ```
> export type SxProps<Theme extends object = {}> =
>   | SystemStyleObject<Theme>
>   | ((theme: Theme) => SystemStyleObject<Theme>)
>   | ReadonlyArray<
>       boolean | SystemStyleObject<Theme> | ((theme: Theme) => SystemStyleObject<Theme>)
>     >;
> ```

We can pass an array with conditional `sx` objects and conditional array elements with boolean values will be ignored:

```
sx={[
  {
    color: defaultColor,
    backgroundColor: defaultBgcolor,
  },
  job.status === 'aborted' && {
    color: color1,
    backgroundColor: bgcolor1,
  },
  job.status === 'queue' && {
    color: color2,
    backgroundColor: bgcolor2,
  }),
  job.status === 'processing' && {
    color: color3,
    backgroundColor: bgcolor3,
  }),
]}
```

Direct flag example:

```
const active = false;

<Alert
  severity="info"
  variant="outlined"
  sx={[
    { borderWidth: 0 },
    !active && { '& .MuiAlert-message': { color: 'text.disabled' } },
  ]}
>
  Some message
</Alert>
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wanting to use the screen size as the condition, there is an easy syntax that can be used to modify the style:

```
<Box sx={{width: {md: MED_WIDTH, lg: LG_WIDTH, xl: XL_WIDTH}}}>
   ...
</Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use their triggers**

For example, on a scroll:

```
import useScrollTrigger from '@mui/material/useScrollTrigger';

//...

const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
disableHysteresis: true,
threshold: 38,
});

//...

<Topbar
colorInvert={trigger ? false : colorInvert}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const a = 1; 

const homeStyle = {
    background: "transparent",
    boxShadow: "none",
    position: "absolute",
    top: 20,
};

sx={a == 1 ? { background: homeStyle.background } : { background: "none" }}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Make sure to always explain why your code works, and/or why the original doesn't! [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).