# How to make different variants of component based on props using styled MUI?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make my component looks different based on props like for example "variant" using `styled` function like below:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/material/styles';

const RemoveButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: 'lightgreen',
}));

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <RemoveButton>Remove Button</RemoveButton>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

So for example what can I do if I want my component to be red when `variant="contained"` and blue when `variant="outlined"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to style the component based on its props using `styled`:

```
const RemoveButton = styled(Button)(({ variant }) => ({
  ...(variant === "contained" && {
    backgroundColor: "red"
  }),
  ...(variant === "outlined" && {
    backgroundColor: "blue"
  })
}));
```

You can also create your own custom variant using `createTheme`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66970148/9449426) answer for more detail.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, nevermind i figure it on my own idk is that recomended solution by mui but that works for me soo:

```
const RemoveButton = styled(Button)(({ theme, ...otherProps }) => ({
  backgroundColor: {"contained":"red","outlined":"green"}[otherProps.variant],
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
}));
```

Comment: If you want to use the fallback value for unknown variant, you can use `??` operator. Related [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69500502/9449426).